# angular2-cli cannot load style error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just created a new angular2 app using `ng new myapp` and I'm having already an error on loading style in index.html. I just added one line in the index.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
```

of course I have added a folder and the file in src/css/styles.css.
And in chrome result shows that

> localhost/:8 GET http://localhost:4200/css/styles.css in red (status =
>   404) not found.

Any idea what would be the error?

When clicking on ctrl + follow link inside the editor, I got the css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach might work but, not recommended. **And, in a project generated by CLI it's highly recommended to add the styles in assets folder**

Assume that the path is './assets/css/styles.css'

**Make sure your path is correct**

Recommended way of doing that is -

In the angular-cli.json styles array 'apps[0].styles' add the following

```
"styles": [
  ...
  "./assets/css/styles.css"
  ...
]
```

Make sure your (default style extension in .angular-cli.json) is

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "css"
}
```

And rerunning with an `npm start` would work

**UPDATE**

`"defaults": {"styleExt": }` is for the purpose of generating components. If the style works fine without changing this, just go ahead with it. See the comments for the reason

Comment: your could add any css file into styles array, even your default ext is css or less

Comment: Yes, default ext is to generate style files when generating the component. Don't know whether that's fixed, but i had issue on compiling scss when i had the default ext as css in my project. Added that to be in the safe side. Thanks for pointing that. @TiepPhan

Comment: just by moving css foler to assets solves the issue. many thanks Saiyaff

Comment: Hope you link it using the .angular-cli.json because even if your approach (linking in the index.html) works fine, it is not recommended. You're most welcome and happy coding @KOul

Answer (score 0):

just `ng new` then for development run `ng serve`, for production run `ng build` or `ng build --prod`, Angular CLI will inject css, js external link for you.

you don't need to specify css link in 
`index.html`

Comment: I need to inject my own css file. My question is why I do have this error loading message ?

Comment: put your css file into `assets` folder, not src.